# Laravel library to handle messages

Tags: laravel-4

I have just created a library class in laravel.

```
class Message {

    public static $data = array();

    public function __construct() {
        // If session has flash data then set it to the data property
        if (Session::has('_messages')) {
            self::$data = Session::flash('_messages');
        }
    }

    public static function set($type, $message, $flash = false) {
        $data = array();

        // Set the message properties to array
        $data['type'] = $type;
        $data['message'] = $message;

        // If the message is a flash message
        if ($flash == true) {
            Session::flash('_messages', $data);
        } else {
            self::$data = $data;
        }
    }

    public static function get() {
        // If the data property is set
        if (count(self::$data)) {
            $data = self::$data;



            // Get the correct view for the message type
            if ($data['type'] == 'success') {
                $view = 'success';
            } elseif ($data['type'] == 'info') {
                $view = 'info';
            } elseif ($data['type'] == 'warning') {
                $view = 'warning';
            } elseif ($data['type'] == 'danger') {
                $view = 'danger';
            } else {
                // Default view
                $view = 'info';
            }

            // Return the view
            $content['body'] = $data['message'];
            return View::make("alerts.{$view}", $content);
        }
    }
}
```

I can use this class in my views calling Message::get(). In the controllers, I can set the message as Message::set('info', 'success message here.'); and it works perfectly fine.

However, I can not use this class for flash messages redirects using Message::set('info', 'success message here.', true). Any idea, whats wrong in this code?

Comment: Yes. Flashed data is retrieved from the session as normal. Using `Session::get('_messages');`

Answer (score 0):

First problem is the constructor function is not called when using the above get and set methods, with minor modification the code is now working. :)

```
class Message {

    public static $data = array();

    public static function set($type, $message, $flash = false) {
        $data = array();

        // Set the message properties to array
        $data['type'] = $type;
        $data['message'] = $message;

        // If the message is a flash message
        if ($flash == true) {
            Session::flash('_messages', $data);
        } else {
            self::$data = $data;
        }
    }

    public static function get() {

        // Check the session if message is available in session
        if (Session::has('_messages')) {
            self::$data = Session::get('_messages');
        }

        // If the data property is set
        if (count(self::$data)) {
            $data = self::$data;

            // Get the correct view for the message type
            if ($data['type'] == 'success') {
                $view = 'success';
            } elseif ($data['type'] == 'info') {
                $view = 'info';
            } elseif ($data['type'] == 'warning') {
                $view = 'warning';
            } elseif ($data['type'] == 'danger') {
                $view = 'danger';
            } else {
                // Default view
                $view = 'info';
            }

            // Return the view
            $content['body'] = $data['message'];
            return View::make("alerts.{$view}", $content);
        }
    }
}
```